# Create a database on a server side

Tags: android, database

I am building an android application where there is a registration/login.
I want to launch it globally so that every one will be able to download it and register/login. There is a need in a constant, permanent database that would not 
shutdown.
What are some good ways to implement it? 
I thought of creating server side database. What should I do?

Comment: Subscribe to a hosting service. Put there your database and webservices, implement RESTful methods in Android.

Comment: There are also hosting services that offer completely configured database servers you can fill with the tables and data you need (e.g. Amazon RDS, though I don't know, if this is the best option). No need to struggle with DB installation and configuration in addition to programming the server-side of your web app.

Comment: Subscribe to a DBaaS like RDS or MongoLAB